# InstaR R package : Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI

Tags: r, instagram-api, instar

I'm exploring your InstaR package to access Instagram data in R.

After registering a client in Instagram and having back my Client ID and Client Secret I got this error.

> {"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"}

The script used is this (app_id and app_secret are fictitious)

```
install.packages("instaR")
library(instaR)


my_oauth <- instaOAuth(app_id="xxxxxxxx", app_secret="yyyyyyyy")
save(my_oauth, file="my_oauth")

alessandrozonin <- getUserMedia( username="alessandrozonin", token=my_oauth )
comments <- getComments( alessandrozonin$id[1], token=my_oauth )
```

Comment: _"your InstaR package"_. I guess @pablo-barbera _might_ see this here. But, since the developer notes where to file bug reports/questions — https://github.com/pablobarbera/instaR/issues — why not ask there directly?

Comment: Hello, steps are completed as described but the problem persist. I've opened an issue in github https://github.com/pablobarbera/instaR/issues/46

Answer (score 0):

From [instaR's documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/instaR/instaR.pdf) in instaOAuth() function:

> Details
>
> To obtan your app_id and app_secret, do the following steps. First, go
>   to http://instagram. com/developer/ and register your application with
>   any name. Then, run the instaOAuth function with your "Client ID" and
>   "Client Secret" as arguments. **It will return a URL, which you will
>   need to paste into the field "OAuth redirect_uri" in your application
>   settings on Instagram. After changing it, press Enter in R. A new
>   browser window will open and sign the token. If everything works works
>   well, you will get a message that says you can return to R.**

From what you wrote in your question and the error message, it seems like you didn't complete the steps in bold correctly.

Comment: Hello, steps are completed as described but the problem persist. I've opened an issue in github https://github.com/pablobarbera/instaR/issues/46